# Always display locales in URL in rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, rails-i18n

So I'm using i18n gem since my rails web-app has to be available in 2 languages : FR and NL.

I made FR the default locale.

My goal is to make sure that in any circumstances, the locales (ie. /fr/ or /nl/) are always shown in the URL.

This is the case with the locale=nl but not the case with the locale=fr being the default locale.

Here an example with a user story:

1. a user arrived on the website and has to select his/her language: let's say "FR" ("FR" being the default locale)
2. the user can now browse the site
3. the user visit the page "Newsfeed" page and his/her URL is **http://localhost:3000/newsfeed**

With this example, the URL should have been **http://localhost:3000/fr/newsfeed** (with the **/fr/** in the URL)

These are my routes:

```
scope '(:locale)', constraints: { locale: /nl|fr/ } do

  resources :articles, :path => 'newsfeed', only: [:index, :edit, :destroy, :update, :new, :create]

  root to: 'languages#select'

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

In my application.rb I have

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
config.i18n.available_locales = [:fr, :nl]
```

In welcome page, where the users have to select their language, I have this

```
<%= link_to "Neederlands", home_path(:locale => 'nl') %> | <%= link_to "Français", home_path(:locale => 'fr') %>
```

To sum up, the URLs for the locale=nl will always show ***http://localhost:3000/nl/newsfeed** but for the default locale **fr** this is not the case and I need to fix that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override `url_for` method.

```
module ActionController::Base
  def url_for(options)
    options.merge! {:locale => "correct locale"}
    super
  end
end
```

This method is defined in other Rails classes also like in views and routing I guess. So you need to override all of them.